# How to find out 'Authentication Status' of specific Named Credential for current user?

Tags: soql, authentication, namedcredentials

Is there any way we can query for and check the `Authentication Status` of a `Named Credential` for the current logged in user?

I found we can query for `Named Credential` sObject, as well as `ExternalDataUserAuth` but none of these have any info or field that can specific whether the user is authenticated successfully or not.

So my question is, what is the best way to find out and alert user that they need to go in and create a Named Credential in there personal settings or that there authentication is facing some problems?

Answer (score 2):

We have exactly the same requirement and since we didn't find an obvious way to find that out, I created a case with Salesforce about this. They confirmed it is currently not possible to query it anywhere. I posted an [idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000J9CncUAF/expose-the-status-of-an-externaldatauserauth) for it.